# What does “it took one away” mean in the line, “For each superpower his brain gave him, it took one away” in encountering a gun attack?

Tags: meaning, phrases

There was the following sentence in the article of Time magazine, titled “Your brain in a shootout: Guns, fear and flawed instincts” dealing with the brain’s function in a life-or-death situation. As Jim Glennon, a lieutenant in the Chicago Police, found himself placed in, one autumn day in 2004 when he was assaulted by a gun-shooter:-
http://swampland.time.com/2013/01/16/your-brain-in-a-shootout-guns-fear-and-flawed-instincts/

> “As happens for most people in life-or-death situations, his brain
>   began to manipulate his perception of time, slowing down the motion as
>   he fled down the corridor.  But for each superpower his brain gave
>   him, **it took one away**. In a flash, his brain reprioritized, shifting
>   finite resources to the cause of survival.

I’m not very clear with what the line, “it took one away” means? What do ‘it’ and ‘one’ represent? Is ‘it’ a substitute for his brain or ‘a superpower’? Is ‘one’ “one of those superpowers” or “him”?

What does 'for" of 'for each superpower' function for? Is it grammatically or rhetorically wrong, if I take ‘for’ away from the line, and say “His brain took away each superpower it gave him”?

How can I rephrase it in a clearer way, without using substitutes, “it” and “one,” (even if the end result includes redundant expressions)?

Comment: "It (his brain) took one (superpower) away"

Comment: To those who casted for “Close” votes: Would you cast “Close” after giving your own answer or comment to each point of my question? Even if it looks a naive and self-explanatory question to you, it can be a big and worth-for-trying-to-ask question for us, non-native English learners like Japanese, Chinese. Korean, Thais, Indonesian, Malaysian, Mexican, Brazilian and you can name it. I don’t think EL&U is the site only allowed to English language specialists and fluent native English speakers.

Comment: Cont. It’s unfair, mean and even coward and shameful to simply cast a ‘Close’ and ‘Down’ vote, without giving any clear reason under your name. At least, it’s autocratic practice, and not a democratic way of behaving, which I think you should attach importance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no doubt that **it** here refers to **his brain**.

It's semantically confusing, because we have to bear in mind that *his brain* is being treated as something different/external to *him*. But structurally it's the same as...

> For each door God closes, He opens another. *(the number of "open doors" remains constant)*.

The "redundant" version of the key sentence in OP's text would thus be...

> But for each superpower his brain gave him, **his brain** took **another superpower** away.

---

To be honest, I don't think native speakers would normally have a problem identifying the referents of **it** and **one** (unless perhaps the *him/his brain* distinction was causing confusion already).

Comment: FumbleFingers. Thanks for a pertinent answer as usual. Your last line is interesting, because as I recall, the most frequent question raised in English classes and English reading circles in Japan is what ‘it’ represents for in the given sentence, whether it represents the antecedent word /clause or postposition or following clause. Sometimes we endlessly argue about what ‘it’ does mean. “It” is always the problem for us in learning English. .

Comment: @Yoichi: Ah, right! I think *now* I see where your confusion might lie! You wonder if it's a [dummy "it"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dummy-it) (which I think of as **existential "it"**) that doesn't necessarily refer to anything in particular. As in *"It's raining"*. Interestingly, in your last sentence above, you could quite reasonably have discarded the quote marks around "it", without (imho) changing the meaning at all.